# Change select 2 version 4 border color when it is opened

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

I have tried to change the border color of select 2 version 4 with when it is opened:

```
.select2-dropdown--above {
    border: 1px solid blue !important;;
    border-bottom: none !important;  

}

.select2-dropdown--below{
    border: 1px solid blue !important;;
    border-top: none !important;     

}
```

Code at: http://jsfiddle.net/7c0Lm033/

Here is what I get:

[image: select 2]

As you can see I can not change the color of select 2 head color. I could not find any unique selector which can change the marked color border.

Comment: see my answer may be it will help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add this to your css:

```
span.select2-selection--multiple[aria-expanded=true] {
    border-color: blue !important;   
}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/7c0Lm033/1/)

Answer (score 5):

see this example : http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/7c0Lm033/2/

Override the css of select2

```
.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple{
   border: 1px solid blue !important;;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use the following code to make the area where your arrows point to blue with this single line of code below

```
$('.select2-selection').css('border-color','blue');
```

Hope it serves a purpose